# Apps Script to move file from root folder to a specific folder in G Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to a move  "kev.csv" that was downloaded via this script from the root Google Drive to another FolderName1/FolderName2/

the file is downloaded however file.MoveTo(folder) doesn't work.
`Failed to upload file with error file.MoveTo is not a function`

using Drive API v3.

```
function uploadfile() {
  try {
    const folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Inbound CSV Files");
    const csvf = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.example.com/example.csv').getBlob();
      let file = { 
      name: 'kev.csv',
      mimeType: 'text/csv'
    };
    file = Drive.Files.create(file, csvf, {'fields': 'id,size'});
    file.MoveTo(folder);
    console.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.size);
      } catch (err){
      console.log ('Failed to upload file with error %s', err.message);
    }
     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- Object Drive_v3.Drive.V3.Schema.File has no method of `MoveTo`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.

I think that in this case, only the Drive service (DriveApp) can be used. When this is reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function uploadfile() {
  try {
    const folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Inbound CSV Files");
    const csvf = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.example.com/example.csv').getBlob();
    let file = {
      name: 'kev.csv',
      mimeType: 'text/csv'
    };
    const fol = folder.hasNext() ? folder.next() : DriveApp.createFolder("Inbound CSV Files");
    const fileObj = fol.createFile(csvf.setContentType(file.mimeType).setName(file.name));
    console.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', fileObj.getId(), fileObj.getSize());
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed to upload file with error %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

- If you want to use Drive API v3, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  function uploadfile() {
    try {
      const folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Inbound CSV Files");
      const csvf = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.example.com/example.csv').getBlob();
      const folderId = folder.hasNext() ? folder.next().getId() : DriveApp.createFolder("Inbound CSV Files").getId();
      const resource = {
        name: 'kev.csv',
        mimeType: 'text/csv',
        parents: [folderId]
      };
      const file = Drive.Files.create(resource, csvf, { 'fields': 'id,size' });
      console.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.size);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Failed to upload file with error %s', err.message);
    }
  }
  ```
- From `FolderName1/FolderName2` of `I'm trying to a move "kev.csv" that was downloaded via this script from the root Google Drive to another FolderName1/FolderName2/`, if you want to put the downloaded file into `FolderName2` under `FolderName1`, how about the following sample script? In this sample, the file is created to the folder `FolderName2` by giving the folder path of `FolderName1/FolderName2`.

  ```js
  function uploadfile() {
    try {

      // Please set folder path. In your question, it's "FolderName1/FolderName2".
      const folderPath = "FolderName1/FolderName2";

      const folder = (folderPath => {
        const folders = folderPath.split("/");
        let parentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
        folders.forEach(f => {
          const fol = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(f);
          parentFolder = fol.hasNext() ? fol.next() : parentFolder.createFolder(f);
        });
        return parentFolder;
      })(folderPath);

      const csvf = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.example.com/example.csv').getBlob();
      let file = {
        name: 'kev.csv',
        mimeType: 'text/csv'
      };
      const fileObj = folder.createFile(csvf.setContentType(file.mimeType).setName(file.name));
      console.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', fileObj.getId(), fileObj.getSize());
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Failed to upload file with error %s', err.message);
    }
  }
  ```
- If you know the folder ID of `FolderName2` of `FolderName1/FolderName2`, you can also use the following sample script.

  ```js
  function uploadfile() {
    try {
      // Please set the folder ID of `FolderName2` of `FolderName1/FolderName2`.
      const folderId = "###";

      const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      const csvf = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.example.com/example.csv').getBlob();
      let file = {
        name: 'kev.csv',
        mimeType: 'text/csv'
      };
      const fileObj = folder.createFile(csvf.setContentType(file.mimeType).setName(file.name));
      console.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', fileObj.getId(), fileObj.getSize());
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Failed to upload file with error %s', err.message);
    }
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [createFile(blob) of Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(BlobSource))
- [Method: files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create)